# Gson parsing not responding

Tags: android, json, gson

I have an ArrayList of custom View objects I want to save to SharedPreferences.
I use Gson.toJson() to serialize the objects, but everytime the function is called, the app stops responding and logcat endlessly writes hundreds of this kind of output:

```
art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 346250(10MB) AllocSpace objects, 185(4MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 27MB/35MB, paused 12.002ms total 112.210ms
```

The problem is the same even when I try doing this in MainActivity.java to ensure that my custom View is not the problem:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String parsedView = gson.toJson(new View(this));
```

But when I try parsing an object that doesn't extend View, it works just fine.

Comment: Why are you serializing a View in the first place?

Comment: To save them to SharedPreferences. So it's not possible to parse a View object into JSON?

Comment: And why do you want to save it to shared preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LogCat is telling you that the OS is freeing (a lot of) memory to make your parsing.

I let you read the structure of the View object : [View object's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java)

As you can see, the strucutre is HUGE ! So your system is making a lot of work here !

You could refer to the @Matt Ball comment : why are you serializing a COMPLETE View object ? If you want to save it in SharedPreferences, store only the needed values : text, clickable, focusable, ... You do not need to store the whole object.

Comment: So in other words I have to write my own object parser? I was trying to avoid that, but I guess I have to do it. Thanks

Comment: Not your own parser. Just an object that contains the data that you actually intend to save.

Comment: OK that's better than I thought, I'll do that. Thanks